# How do I use postgis st_setvalue to update all cells in a tile?

Tags: postgresql, calculator, postgis, raster, tiles

I have 2 small rasters in postgis-enabled db: a DEM and a streams/ponds layer. Both are stored as 10x10 tiles and have same srid and cell size. I want to "burn" the streams/ponds into the DEM (i.e. raster calculator). I tried ST_MapAlgebra, but could not figure out how to ignore the nodata cells in the stream/pond layer. Now I'm trying to simply update the DEM using ST_SetValue. The following code appears to only update one cell per tile (see image). If I don't include the st_intersects() clause, it runs forever (even if I only pass in a single point to update a single cell). I assume it might work if rasters were not stored as tiles, but I'd rather not do that.

```
update dem_clip d set rast = st_setvalue(d.rast, geom, st_value(d.rast,geom) - 1000)
from (select ((st_pixelascentroids(rast)).geom) from stream_clip) s
where st_intersects(d.rast,s.geom);
```

[what I want (streams burned into DEM)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gletx.png)

[what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4hZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

This function solves my problem. It's slow, but I'm not in a rush. I'm certain it can be improved.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_vals(g1 geometry, v1 integer)
 RETURNS void as $$
begin 
update dem_clip_test set rast = 
st_setvalue(rast, g1, 
st_value(rast,g1) + v1)
where st_intersects(rast,g1);
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select update_vals(geom, -1000) from 
(select ((st_pixelascentroids(rast)).geom) from stream_clip) s;
```